# How to get Windows 7 to automatically connect to an ad-hoc network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, automation, ad-hoc-network

I have two machines - one is running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and the other is running Windows 7 Starter Edition (32-bit).

The Ubuntu machine is connected to the Internet via the `eth0` interface. That machine also has a wireless network interface (`wlan0`) that is currently functioning as an ad-hoc network.

I can connect to the ad-hoc network just fine with the Windows machine but each time I wish to do so, I must manually initiate the connection and enter the password.

Is there some way to instruct Windows to automatically connect to this network (an option I have for standard wireless networks but not ad-hoc networks)?

Comment: Have you tried using `netsh` with `wlan connect` ? In my vista it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **Starter edition** of Windows 7 and, according to Microsoft:

> Ad hoc networking. A computer running Windows 7 Starter can't create
>   an ad hoc network (also called a computer-to-computer network), but it
>   can be part of an ad hoc network. Ad hoc networks are often used for a
>   specific purpose, such as playing a multiplayer computer game.

[Networking in Windows 7 Starter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-in-Windows-7-Starter)

You may start the ad hoc connection with *netsh* as pointed in comments but the password must be entered each time. Windows 7 Starter edition can't remember the password like in professional edition... (same problem with the command runas for example: it's a "feature"...)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use your Ubuntu machine in infrastructure mode as a wifi hotspot just like any router/access point instead of ad-hoc mode?

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

Otherwise if you really need ad-hoc, you can place a shortcut to

```
netsh wlan connect YOURSSID
```

in your startup folder.  (Same concept as @harrymc without using task scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

There is no really automatic way of doing so in Windows, but here are some possibilities.

The article [Connect to Wi-Fi Ad-Hoc Networks Automatically with Windows Vista](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/ad-hoc-networks-routing/) uses
the Windows Scheduler to schedule the connection to the ad-hoc network 1 minute after login.
This will supposedly fail if another network connection is already established.

[Maxidix Wifi Suite](http://www.maxidix.com/) is a commercial product with trial that supports auto connections to ad-hoc networks. At the moment it's on sale for $10 instead of $30.
(I have no experience with this product.)